# A princess falls in love with a lowly stable boy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

A princess falls in love with a lowly stable boy. The king cannot stand to see his daughter marry a commoner, but he also can't say no to her.He proposes a deal.

> He says that they will all go down to the beach where he will select 2
>   stones - one white and one black.He will put them both in a bag and
>   allow the princess to reach into the bag and select one, without
>   looking. If she picks the white, the king will allow the marriage.If
>   she picks the black, there will be no wedding and the stable boy will
>   be banned from the kingdom.

The princess is not happy about this, but she figures that it is the best chance she has. The king, the princess and the royal court go down to the beach. The king bends down to select the rocks, but the princess sees that instead of one white and one black, the king selects 2 black stones.This would mean that no matter which she picks, she will lose her love.

The king holds out the bag to the princess.What can she do to get her way and be with her love?

Comment: I was searching for the original all this time.....

Answer (score 6):

> And thus, the princess reached into the bag, and drew a stone. She kept it concealed in her hand. 
> Whith a smirk, she turned the bag upside down, letting the second black stone hit the beach sand with a soft sound.
>  "ah, your Majesty, dearest father .. see? the remaining stone is black, surely I picked the white"
>  ... The King did not wish to lose face by showing his treachery, and reluctantly agreed to the weddind.

Answer (score 1):

> She can draw out 1 stone and then drop it immediately, and then acting all shy and innocent can say "Oh deary me, I dropped the one I choose, but how to find it, this beach is full of black and white stones? So lets look inside of the bag"

So,

> Inside the bag will be remaining black stone(implying that princess has picked up white stone), and it will be win for princess

And they live happily ever after!!

Comment: The princess may throw the stone she picked into the sea. And asked to see for other stone in the bag.

Comment: @SathiReddy yes, she can, but then remaining people can doubt her, if she acts like she dropped it accidentally, she can wriggle her way through it(this is what I though)